# How can I make django show me exceptions from functions called in templates?

Tags: django, exception, django-templates

Django has the (usually fine) behaviour of turning exceptions in templates into empty strings.  So if I do `{{object.fn_which_throws_exception}}` I just get an empty string.  But sometimes I would like to know something about the exception: is there any way to make django present or log the details of such exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `runserver` you could use pdb to step through the code.

Add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` above the problematic code. Go to the URL in question in your browser and pdb should pause the execution and let you step through the code line by line.

http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're in your development environment, make sure both `DEBUG` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` are set to `True`.

If you're in a production environment, your best bet is to add [django-sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry) to your project. It tracks all the info you would get running with `DEBUG=True`. It's an absolutely amazing piece of software that will save you infinite amounts of time when things go wrong.

EDIT: Oh, one last thing. You can always wrap your code in a `try... except` block and return the exception that way:

```
def fn_which_throws_exception():
    import sys
    try:
        # code that might raise exception
    except:
        return sys.exc_info()
```

Comment: I have DEBUG and TEMPLATE_DEBUG set to True (as was the default) -- you're suggesting that that should be giving me exception info somewhere?

Comment: Yes, if there's any exception raised, and both of those are set to true, you should get an error page with a traceback.

Comment: According to the django docs, TEMPLATE_DEBUG reports TemplateSyntaxError exceptions, as opposed to exceptions from functions I call from a template.  My observation is that it doesn't do anything with exceptions in functions that I call from a template, have you actually tried that?

Comment: Correct, TEMPLATE_DEBUG just covers exceptions encountered in processing template tags and such. But, DEBUG covers everything else. If you have an exception, any exception, that is unhandled in your code, it should generate an error page when in debug mode.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6907
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8031

Comment: Both of those tickets refer to `AttributeError` exceptions. While, technically, yes, there is *one* exception that won't be raised in a template, that is by design. A missing attribute == `None` in templates to make it easier to design templates without having to use something like `hasattr` which would not even be possible in Django templates, because it would require passing arguments to the method.